# How to generate X509 certificate thumbprint?

Tags: security, x509certificate, single-sign-on

I installed a plugin on my website that handles single sign-on to Access Control Services (ACS). As part of the setup, there is a space to enter "X509 certificate thumbprint (used for issuer URL token signing) – The token signing certificate thumbprint". What am I supposed to enter in there?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The certificate thumbprint is a hash of the public key of the certificate ([Wiki: Public key certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate)). Comodo has a HowTo for retrieving it: [Comodo](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=1274).

With openssl:

```
openssl x509 -in CERTIFICATE_FILE -fingerprint -noout
```

Comment: As mentioned by user203508, this is not correct. The certificate thumbprint is a hash of the whole certificate in DER format. Hash function is stored as part of the cert in thumbprint algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

> > The certificate thumbprint is a hash of the public key of the certificate

Really, not.

Thumbprint calculated from whole certificate in DER format.
You can get it with -fingerprint flag of openssl x509, for example, or using any hash calculation tool.

Comment: first your answer should say, what has to be entered or not. Then give the explanation.